# Rewrite MFC DLL with C#?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, mfc, interop

I have a plugin DLL that I've written in C++ MFC loaded by a 3rd party application presumably written in C++ with MFC.  My DLL has a GUI interface and is based on CWinApp; I guess somehow the message pump of my plugin cooperates with the message pump of the main app (?)  I believe my DLL is probably loaded via LoadLibrary and started via a call to an exported function in my DLL.  My plugin calls functions and classes that the 3rd party application exposes via a static lib that my DLL links against.

This is fine but working with MFC/C++ is frustrating as compared to working in WinForms and C#.  So I'm wondering if it would be possible to have my DLL not use MFC but instead use winforms and C#?  Is there some way this could work?  I'm imagining I guess the DLL written in C# that exports a function that is called from the 3rd party app and then this starting a winforms app?  Also my DLL needs to link to a static C++ library in order to interop with the 3rd party application.  Would that be possible to access from C#?  Or if not directly possible maybe I can write some kind of wrapper?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to wrap your C# dll with a C++ dll.  Just create a shell in managed C++ that accepts whatever calls need to be handled from the main program.  It can then call into the C# dll and let it handle all the work.